# Laravel eloquent top 10 based on a unique count of rows that exist in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

Essentially, what i am trying to achieve is to return X results ordered by a unique count of rows that exist in pivot table (polymorphic relation).

A little background, when a user reaches a profile page, a `$profile->hit()` function is called, this function logs a visit against the entity in a `visitors` table.

All this functionality is handle in a trait that I can assign to any model (currently `Profile` and `Track`).

In order to get these 'popular' posts, I will need to add a `scopePopular` to my trait. So in the controller I can call `$profile->popular(10)->get();`.

The count of visitors used to calculate these popular posts must be unique rows based on the `ip_address` column in my `visitors` table.

Here is the `visitors` table migration:

```
Schema::create('visitors', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->uuid('visitorable_id');
    $table->string('visitorable_type');

    $table->string('isp')->nullable();
    $table->string('country_code')->nullable();
    $table->string('country')->nullable();
    $table->string('city')->nullable();
    $table->string('region')->nullable();
    $table->string('region_name')->nullable();
    $table->string('ip_address')->nullable();
    $table->string('timezone')->nullable();
    $table->string('zip_code')->nullable();
    $table->string('latitude')->nullable();
    $table->string('longitude')->nullable();

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and the relationship in my `VistorableTrait` that gets added to models :

```
public function visitors()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Visitor', 'visitorable');
}
```

How would I go about doing this using the query builder in my popular scope?

**Update**

I have managed to get this far with my scope:

```
public function scopePopular($query, $limit = 10)
{
    $query->leftJoin('visitors', function($q) {
        $q->where('visitors.visitorable_id', '=', 'db885a18-f0b7-4f55-9d93-743fbb5d9c94');
        $q->where('visitors.visitorable_type', '=', 'App\Profile');
    })
    ->groupBy('profiles.id')
    ->limit($limit);
}
```

So this gets all the visitor rows where for the profile (currently a hardcoded id & type) now I need a way to count the unique rows in visitors and order the profiles by this?

Answer (score 0):

In the join you could turn in into a subquery, this would make it join based on `ip_address` being unique

```
$visitors->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(id) visits, UNIQUE(ip_address) FROM `visitors`) visitors'), function($join)
        {
            $join->on('visitors.visitorable_id', '=', 'profile.id');
            $join->where('visitors.visitorable_type', '=', 'App\Profile');
        })
```

Untested and might need some adjustment to work correctly, but the end result is a custom version of the visitors table, prefiltered before joining.

The result I am thinking this would result in is an extra field when joined of `visits` that would be attached to every profile, so you can order by that.

Comment: I understand the logic here but appears to be a few Syntax errors. SQL isn't really my strongest point at the moment. 

I have put this in my scope and the resulting query looks like this:

`select * from `profiles` inner join `profile_genres` on `profiles`.`id` = `profile_genres`.`profile_id` left join (SELECT COUNT(id) visits, UNIQUE(ip_address) FROM `visitors`) visitors on `visitors`.`visitorable_id` = `db885a18-f0b7-4f55-9d93-743fbb5d9c94` and `visitors`.`visitorable_type` = ? where `profile_genres`.`genre_id` = ? and `profiles`.`deleted_at` is null`

Comment: Obviously I have replaced all the ? with my details when running in DBeaver. One mistake could be the `visitors on `. 

Removing the `visitors` gets a little further but still results in an error :(

Comment: Yes I had put the idea in but it will take some tinkering to work, I have done similar things in the past and I am sure it "can" work. but one thing is the select should likely be `profiles.*, visitors.visits` since otherwise it will try to get all and could result in column conflicts. Also the on should connect to the id of the profile, rather then a string (not using where since its in join)

Comment: Ok, Ill have to take a look at this tomorrow. 

The issue is that this on a trait in a scope function. So all the query other than what you have shown is being generated from the model and other traits (Soft Deletes etc.). 

That string is my ID, I'm using UUID's

Comment: Thanks for throwing it out there, like I said I understand the logic and that on the face of it appears to be sound.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Redis to achieve this, creating a class to handle the `visits`.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class ProfileVisits
{
    /**
     * This will record a visit in a key
     * called profile_visits with the profile's id and name...
     *
     * @param Profile $profile
     */
    public function push($profile)
    {
        Redis::zincrby('profile_visits', 1, json_encode([
            'id' => $profile->id,
            'name' => $profile->name
        ]));
    }

    /**
     * And this will get back the results
     * ordered by the number of visits.
     *
     * @param int $take
     * @return stdObject
     */
    public function get($take = 10)
    {
        return array_map('json_decode', Redis::zrevrange('profile_visits', 0, $take));
    }
}
```

So in your `->hit()` method you can do this:

```
public function hit()
{
    // your logic here...
    (new ProfileVisits)->push($this); // $this is a Profile instance, right?
}
```

And in finally in your controller:

```
$visits = (new ProfileVisits)->get();
```

I hope this answer can be helpful.

Comment: Sorry but that is not helpful, I am using a polymorphic relationship on a trait so that I can easily store additional data as and when needed. Yes, this is a simple approach but does not provide me with the flexibility and data that I need.

Comment: You can use Redis, too.